# bs4 list comprehension with 'if' statement

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

I'm trying to add the text of each table row to my list if the table row contains text. I want to do this using list comprehension.

Here's what I tried

```
 listt2 = [s.span.text for s in soup.find_all('tr') if s.span.text]
```

Here's the error

```
    listt2 = [s.span.text for s in soup.find_all('tr') if s.span.text]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Here's 1 'tr' that contains a span tag:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="cell--section-end cell--link cell--link__icon">
        <a data-analytics="[Competitions] - German Bundesliga" href="/football/german-bundesliga/event/26301018" class="cell--link__link  cell-text">
            <i class="i accordion__title-icon--green accordion__title-icon--right" data-char=""></i>            <b class="cell-text__line cell-text__line--icon">
                <span class="competitions-team-name  js-ev-desc">1. FC Köln v 1899 Hoffenheim</span>
            </b>

                    </a>
    </td>

<tr>
```

Here's Another that doesn't:

```
<tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="group-header">
            Sat 14:30        </td>
    </tr>
```

Please note there are many more tr tags on this page

Comment: Seems that some `<tr>` tags don't contain `<span>` tags, so `s.span` returns `None`. You need to handle that situation.

Comment: some don't, some do, i'm trying to get the ones that do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only `<tr>` tags which contain `<span>` tag, you can use this list comprehension:

```
listt2 = [s.span.text for s in soup.select('tr:has(span)') if s.span.text]
```

---

EDIT:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="cell--section-end cell--link cell--link__icon">
        <a data-analytics="[Competitions] - German Bundesliga" href="/football/german-bundesliga/event/26301018" class="cell--link__link  cell-text">
            <i class="i accordion__title-icon--green accordion__title-icon--right" data-char=""></i>            <b class="cell-text__line cell-text__line--icon">
                <span class="competitions-team-name  js-ev-desc">1. FC Köln v 1899 Hoffenheim</span>
            </b>

                    </a>
    </td>

<tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

listt2 = [s.span.text for s in soup.select('tr:has(span)') if s.span.text]

print(listt2)
```

Prints:

```
['1. FC Köln v 1899 Hoffenheim']
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check that `span is not None` before looking for `span.text`.

```
listt2 = [s.span.text for s in soup.find_all('tr') if s.span is not None and s.span.text]
```

Because of [short-circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), `s.span.text` is never evaluated if `s.span is None` because `False and *` is `False`